# Mathematical relation between number of digits and the value of the number

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

I am trying to figure out the mathematical relation between a number and the number of digits that number has.
For e.g. Relation between 0, 1, 2...9 and 1,

```
     or between 10, 11, 12...99 and 2, 

     or between 100, 101, 102...999 and 3, 

     or between 1000, 1001,...5000, 5001, ...9999 and 4.
```

So given a number having 'n' digits whose value is 'x', I want to express it as

```
n = f(x)
```

I could figure out the following:

```
x = ∑(10^i * xi)  where i=1 to n.  Where xi is the digit at position i.
```

So x = x1 + 10*x2 + 10^2*x3 + ... + 10^n*xn

Where x1, x2, x3 etc. are digits at unit, tenth, hundredth positions respectively.

I am surely missing something here.  Any help is appreciated

Thanks,

Sid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

- If a number $n$ has $k$ digits, then $10^{k-1} \le n < 10^{k}$.
- If a number $n$ has $k$ digits, then $k = \lfloor\log n\rfloor + 1$ where $\log$ is to base $10$.

Replace $10$ with $b$ if you're using a different base $b$.

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing anything.

A representation of a number $x$ in base $d$ is the (unique) sum $x=\sum_{i=0}^n a_id^i$ with $0\le a_i<d$ for all $0\le i\le n$ (the $a_i$'s are the digits in that base).

I'm not sure what else you want to find.

Comment: Well, it would probably be worth mentioning [logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) and the formula $f(x) = \lfloor \log_{10}(x) \rfloor + 1$ for the number of digits of $x$.

Comment: Yes. Kudos for ShreevastaR.